# Strange behavior with size of reference type c#

Tags: c#, reference, size, storage, clr

I have found some strange behavior and I want to know the reason for this.
Consider we have the following class

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
Class A
{
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
Class Test
{
   A a;

}
```

and ..

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Test))
```

in this case size = 1, so I can guess that a is 1 byte. When I change the Test class in this way

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
Class Test
{
   int a;

}
```

the size = 4 byte, as expected for int type.

But when I put it together, I expect that the size will 4+1 = 5bytes. but I get this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
Class Test
{
   A a;
   int x;
}
```

size = 16. I want to know why in this case int takes 8 bytes?

Comment: Just FYI, it's usually better to copy and paste your actual code. Here you have `Class` uppercased, which obviously isn't correct C# and won't compile.

Comment: Also, I get 1 for your first test, not 8. https://dotnetfiddle.net/J3g1P7

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Yes, you are right I have mistaken for the first case, but the third case is 8 byte, but why 8 if 4 bytes for int and 1 for A. dotnetfiddle.net/J3g1P7

Answer (score 0):

Running the third case in fiddle reports 8 bytes for me.

From the page on the [pack attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.7):

> - The alignment of the type is the size of its largest element (1, 2, 4, 8, etc., bytes) or the specified packing size, whichever is smaller.
> - Padding is added between fields to satisfy the alignment requirements.

In other words, in your third case the struct has an alignment of 4, so each element is padded to be of this size. You can use `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]` attribute to force a 1-byte alignment and the whole struct to take 5 bytes.

The reason for all this is that access to unaligned memory may be slower on some architectures.